# How to modify a helm chart during the CI pipeline?

Tags: charts, kubernetes-helm, cicd

I have an application packaged as a helm chart, and I want to set up a Continuous Deployment pipeline using a tool like ArgoCD, such that whenever there is a new version of the docker image (new image TAG) there will be a new chart packaged for that new image and finally deployed to my k8s cluster.
So, I'm looking for a proper way of modifying the chart manifests in the CI part and then package it, push it to repo, pull it, deploy it?
is it ok to use command like sed to change the manifests, or is there a more proper way of making the modification?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change the manifest for a Helm chart; you'd almost always pass the image tag as a Helm value.  You could edit the `values.yaml` file if you needed source control to reflect the deployment history.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider combining the steps using [kbld](https://carvel.dev/kbld/docs/v0.32.0/). That can combine steps of

- building the container (with docker build, pack or a couple other options),
- pushing the container to a registry, and
- substituting the name of the image for full name with sha256 hash in yaml files.

  - alternatively it can emit a “lock” file to do the substitution later.

Either you can

- run the `values.yaml` through it during build,
- put a separate `yaml` file in the chart that you will load with the `.File` API, or
- save the lock file and use `kbld` as post-render filter.

You'll still have to modify the `version` and `appVersion` in `Chart.yaml`. I'd say `sed` is good enough for that.

In recent project I cobbled together a project-specific python script to do the versioning (to make it understand semver) and bundle the lock file for operations to use, but depends on the exact workflow you'd like.